# 301 Dynamic Pages Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dynamic, get

Hi I tried various methods with modewriter in htaccess shown in other threads. I want to redirect my url from `www.example.com/categories.php?category=1` to `www.example.com/categories/science`.

I would really appreciate an example too where I'm wrong. Thank You.

Comment: How do you get from `1` to `science`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it is just this one URL you want to redirect it would be like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^categories.php$ www.example.com/categories/science/? [L,R=301]
```

This is in case you are using a .htaccess file, otherwise add a prepending slash:

```
RewriteRule ^/categories.php$ www.example.com/categories/science/? [L,R=301]
```

The querystring wil be discarded. Only put [R] if you want to show it to the user in the addressbar of the browser. Consider which status you want to serve, Google likes 301 if it's permanent.

Next you have to catch the incoming request with an index.php in the directory www.example.com/categories/science

good luck!

Comment: Hi thank you for your fast reply i tried it in my htaccess file and when i load my page the url goes like this http://example.com/www.example.com/categories/science/ with a 404 page not found any thoughts?I don't know if other lanes like this that i used for redirecting from non www address to www address and redirecting my index.php page to my website are causing any problems?I removed them and tried only with your suggestion but the address is still the same like page 404 not found.

Comment: This is the code that i used before
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.come
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.example.com/

Comment: It looks like you other rule is causing the unmeant redirect. Also it could be that your testing is getting troubled by cache of the browser. Try flushing that, restarting the browser, and while testing, don't use [R=301] but plain [R].
The last rule will interfere with your new index.php

Comment: Your comment, quote: "I removed them and tried only with your suggestion but the address is still the same like page 404 not found" is what i mean by the cache of the browser that serves up the old stuff. The rule i gave should work for you when you remove the other rules.

My comment "The last rule will interfere with your new index.php" is about your rewrite rule:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ example.com - 
You don't want to have your new www.example.com/categories/science/index.php being rewritten to example.com/www.example.com/categories/science